# How to prevent in an unsigned imposter app from listening to the FCM notifications for your app?

Tags: android, security, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am(was) planning to use Firebase messaging to send all my users of my Android app a coupon code for some non-phone/app related services as part of my business. I would like to restrict such messages to my SIGNED Android app downloaded from the Google Play store with my package name...

However, I noticed that if I just created an unsigned/debug android app with the exact same package name, it could also listen to topic messages/notifications or user-segmented messages/notifications sent from the FCM console to my app's package name.

Is there a way to secure FCM messages sent over a topic or user-segmented send from imposter apps with your package name?

Also, can someone explain to me what the purpose of the "SHA certificate fingerprints" configurations in your FCM project is for... I thought the purpose of this was to restrict access of FCM to just apps signed with a certificate matching the SHA1 hash, but apparently that's not what it's for (or if it is, it isn't working).

[FCM Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmKFk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Does your debug app have a suffix called debug? And has it been automatically included by Android Studio to firebase?

Also, the app doesn't need to be signed to get access to FCM notifications, the App package name and SHA is enough.

Edit* check if:

```
buildTypes {

    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
    }}
```

[image]

If you don't want the debug version, add suffix and delete debug from list of apps.

Comment: How is an app not signed and have a SHA?

And, I'm assuming the google-services.json content can easily be extracted from a signed/downloaded app from the app store via decompilation... So we can assume all the information in the google-services.json file can be copied over into an imposter app.... Why would a debug app suffix matter? It doesn't seem like the SHA configuration in the FCM project matters. I can change it to anything, and it doesn't prevent any app from receiving the message(s).

Comment: SHA is generated when connecting IDE to firebase. For testing reasons as well.

Comment: So you are adding .debug to debug builds? My point was, I don't want someone to make a fake app with the same applicationId to listen to my events. I thought that the SHA would take care of that. But it doesn't seem to.

Comment: I wrote an answer but I just realized that it was a stupid one :P So yea, if you decompile the json file and add it then probably nothing keeps it from listening to your events.